# How to return count if column values conatains specific string in it

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have one table which have 20 different columns, 4 of which are used to store image names.

e.g.

```
img01 = abcdef_X
img02 = jklmno
img03 = tuvxys_X
img04 = awstyt_X
```

can i have sql query to return a count of these 4 columns which contains '_X' in it????

Is it possible???

Comment: yeah, but i want to perform it on 4 different columns & return the count

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want to find `_X` anywhere in the column, you can try the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM yourTable
WHERE col LIKE '%[_]X%'
```

If you want to count matches across four columns, where a match is defined as any of four columns matching (for a total possible match score of 4), then you could try:

```
SELECT
    col1, col2, col3, col4,
    (CASE WHEN col1 LIKE '%[_]X%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
     CASE WHEN col2 LIKE '%[_]X%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
     CASE WHEN col3 LIKE '%[_]X%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
     CASE WHEN col4 LIKE '%[_]X%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS cnt
FROM yourTable
```

If, as your sample data imply, you only want to match this pattern at the end of a string, you can use `LIKE '%[_]X` instead.

I answered because your question is slightly more complicated than the above comments imply, since you want to match a literal underscore with `LIKE`.  In this case, we can escape underscore by putting into square brackets.

Comment: is it possible to write the same query on 4 different columns, or i just i have to write  WHERE col1 like.., col2 like.., col3 like..

Comment: What are you trying to count exactly?  If one of four columns matches, how do we count this?

Comment: yes that's what i am saying if one out of four matches '_X' can i return count as 1??

Comment: this query looks great, but i have 2 columns which contains '_X' in it, but still it's returning count as 1, idially it must return 2

Comment: I'll update again.  This isn't what you said above however.

Comment: Can i retrieve all columns + the count in said solution in same query?

Comment: I tried it, but it shows : Column 'tblName.ID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Sorry, don't use `SUM()`, instead just add the 4 `CASE` expressions by hand.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM yourTable
WHERE (img01  LIKE '%[_]X%') or (img02 LIKE '%[_]X%') or (img03 LIKE '%[_]X%') or (img04  LIKE '%[_]X%')
```

if you want to make sure all the columns has the string theen use AND instead of OR

Comment: why does it returns count as 1 if there are 2 columns which contains '_X' in it?

Comment: the columns are two but row is 1 i guess count funcionality dosent count columns it count rows