# Count IF Function Equivalent

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, count

I have four columns: A Team, B Team, C Team, D Team.

Each row entry can contain either a Yes or No in each of the columns. For example like so:

```
A Team    B Team    C Team    D Team
------------------------------------
Yes       Yes       No        No
```

I'm looking to create an additional column `NumberofTeams` that sums wherever there is a yes. So in this case it would return 2 - indicating that 2 teams are involved.

I was going to attempt it via a `CASE` function, but believe this would have to cover every single permutation?

```
select 
    *, 
    NumberofTeams = select case 
                              when [A Team] = 'Yes' and [B Team] = 'Yes' 
                                 then 2 
                              when [A Team] = 'Yes' and [C Team] = 'Yes' 
                                 then 2
```

and so on.

If there's a 'cleaner' way?

Comment: It would be "cleaner" if you used a [`bit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/bit-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) for each true/false value rather than prose. That would also avoid dealing with values like `'Y'`, `'?'` and `'Ω'`. As a numeric data type, bits are easier to add.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way to do it:

```
select
    t.*,
    case when [A Team] = 'Yes' then 1 else 0 end
        + case when [B Team] = 'Yes' then 1 else 0 end
        + case when [C Team] = 'Yes' then 1 else 0 end
        + case when [D Team] = 'Yes' then 1 else 0 end
        as NumberOfTeams
from mytable t
```

Answer (score 1):

Found my answer here: [How to return count if column values conatains specific string in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45294988/how-to-return-count-if-column-values-conatains-specific-string-in-it)

For anyone that's wondering:

```
SELECT
    col1, col2, col3, col4,
    (CASE WHEN col1 LIKE '%[_]X%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
     CASE WHEN col2 LIKE '%[_]X%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
     CASE WHEN col3 LIKE '%[_]X%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
     CASE WHEN col4 LIKE '%[_]X%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS cnt
FROM yourTable
```

Comment: It isn't clear that counting columns containing `'_X'` will help the OP, but only you would know.

Answer (score 0):

If the only choices are `'Yes'` and `'No'` then you can take a shortcut. Since they differ in length by `1` you can add the lengths of the strings and subtract the length of the shorter string for each column. More simply, concatenate the strings and take the overall length and subtract enough to account for no's:

```
declare @Samples as Table ( ATeam VarChar(3), BTeam VarChar(3), CTeam VarChar(3), DTeam VarChar(3) );
insert into @Samples values ( 'No', 'No', 'No', 'No' ), ( 'Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'No' ), ( 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes' );

select *, Len( ATeam + BTeam + CTeam + DTeam ) - 8 as NumberOfTeams
  from @Samples;
```